# Nuclear forces so strong that they can attract other atoms too?

Tags: nuclear-physics, protons

this pic is from the book the theory of everything by Stephen Hawking:

[image: ![enter image description here]

My question is that whether the nuclear forces inside the atom are so strong that they can attract other atoms (para 1, line -4&5). And also what are the nuclear forces inside atom besides the proton?

Comment: "At the big bang itself, the universe had zero size ..."  A example of why I don't like Hawking as an author.

Comment: Note that you wrote "atoms" in your subject.  Do you really mean atoms?  I don't see what Hawking's quote has to do with atoms.  I guess that means that I don't understand your question.

Comment: So what do you think that he meant by PARTICLES here?

Comment: "... and so must have been infinitely hot."   Really?  It's a shame that his books are so popular.  At best he makes misleading statements.  At worst he's just wrong.  He knows better, of course, but he has translated his knowledge to popular language very poorly.

Comment: *Particles*:  he means anything.  Atoms, molecules, electrons, quarks ...  whatever happens to be stable at the age of the universe under consideration.  When he mentions nuclear force in this context, he means a time when the universe was filled with nucleons, and electrons ... no atoms yet.  The nucleons are moving too fast to capture one another, so no nuclei form.  The universe needs to cool a bit more before nuclei form, and then cool some more before atoms form.   An atom can't attract another atom via the nuclear force. (The force is negligibly weak at atomic distances.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page is about the [history of the creation of the universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_of_the_universe):

[image: chronology]

The force that holds the quarks within the proton and the neutron is the strong force, with respect to [all other forces](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/funfor.html) the strongest, and they are in the quantum mechanical framework.

On the left,  during the inflation period, the quarks together with the gluons are free in a plasma in a soup with electrons and positrons, photons and neutrinos and the rest of the elementary particles in the [standard model table.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) Then protons and neutrons formed, the quarks pulling each other with the strong force , and once formed they were trapped as the universe cooled, and  the universe was filled :

> [with a uniform glow from a white-ho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background)t fog of hydrogen plasma. As the universe expanded, both the plasma and the radiation filling it grew cooler. When the universe cooled enough, protons and electrons combined to form neutral hydrogen atoms. These atoms could no longer absorb the thermal radiation, and so the universe became transparent instead of being an opaque fog.[3](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/funfor.html)

this is the colorful "afterglow light pattern" time in the plot.

From then on the nuclear forces that formed the rest of the elements are  residual  forces from the bound quarks within the protons and neutrons. The spill over is still attractive and thus forms the [periodic  table of elements.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_table). Thus the [nuclear force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_force) is

> is the force between protons and neutrons, subatomic particles that are collectively called nucleons. The nuclear force is responsible for binding protons and neutrons into atomic nuclei. Neutrons and protons are affected by the nuclear force almost identically. Since protons have charge +1 e, they experience a strong electric field repulsion (following Coulomb's law) that tends to push them apart, but at short range the attractive nuclear force overcomes the repulsive electromagnetic force. The mass of a nucleus is less than the sum total of the individual masses of the protons and neutrons which form it.

Atoms are attracted to atoms through electromagnetism [covalent bonds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covalent_bond), [ionic bonding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionic_bonding)s and  electromagnetic [residual forces,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_force). The nuclear force is too short range to affect the atoms: size of nucleus order of 10^-15 cm, size of atom order 10^-10 ; and the electron shells do not allow closer contact.

Comment: thanks @anna v.  
BUT,  does this mean that the book is wrong?( para -1 , line4&5) – IN 4TH & 5 line it is written that particles can  escape any attraction towards each other caused by NUCLEAR or electromagnetic forces..

Comment: It is correct. When temperatures are high there is high kinetic energy and high kinetic energy overcomes  the corresponding attraction, at the quark gluon plasma state it is the strong force that is overcome by the kinetic energy, at the hydrogen plasma  stage the electromagnetic. Think of comets with high kinetic energy, they are not caught or they do not fall in the sun.

Comment: I got it...(^^)....thnks anna v

Answer (score 1):

> My question is that whether the nuclear forces inside the atom are so strong that they can attract other atoms (see image).

The [strong nuclear force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_interaction) is very strong and has to be because it must resist the electromagnetic repulsion of the protons at very small ranges.

But the strong nuclear force falls off much more rapidly with distance and it's negligible outside typical nuclei sizes.  The [Yukawa potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukawa_potential) will given you an idea of this behavior.

> And also what are the nuclear forces inside atom besides the proton?

As that Wikipedia article explains, protons and neutrons are made up of quarks, and it is the interaction of quarks that is responsible for the strong nuclear force.

This wikipedia article ( where would we be without it ? ) deals gives a reasonable overview of the [fundamental "forces"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_interaction) at work.

Comment: so, does this mean that the book is wrong?( para -1 , line-4&5)

Comment: No. What it says is that at very high kinetic energy, even the strong force and electromagnetic forces are outmatched by kinetic energy. But, at lower kinetic energy, the strong force binds quarks into hadrons, at even lower kinetic energies, the residual strong force binds protons and neutrons into atomic nuclei, and at lower still kinetic energies (i.e. the amount of kinetic energy prevailing during 99.99999% + of the last 13.8 billion years), the electromagnetic force binds atoms into molecules. The lines don't say what you think they are saying. Read it again slowly.

Comment: Thnks a lot ohwilleke